# вывод данных из json файла на html странице

Tags: html, json

это код в json

```
{
  "SSDP": "WebSockets- Server",
  "ssidAP": "WiFi",
  "passwordAP": "",
  "ssid": "",
  "password": "",
  "timezone": 8
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <a href='index.htm'>Главная</a>
  <a href="pult.htm">Пульт</a>

</div>

<table class="details">
  <caption>Умная комната</caption>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <form name="lamp" method="post" action="Reley">
        <p align="center">Котел<input type="submit" name="state" value="плюс"> <input type="submit" name="state" value="минус">
        </p>
      </form>
      <form name="lamp" method="get" action="Reley">

      </form>
      <div>
        <div id="placeholder">ssidAP:</div>
        <script src="config.json"></script>
        <script>
          $.getJSON('config.json', function(data) {
            var output = "<ul>";
            for (var i in data) {
              output += "<li>" + data[i].ssidAP + "</li>";
            }

            output += "</ul>";
            document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML = output;
          });
        </script>
      </div>
      <p>

      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Это код `html` файла, прикрепленный `json` файл не выводится на странице,в чем проблема? И как её решить?

> json файл лежит в одной папке с html.

Comment: В обработчик попадаете? `console.log("JSON", data);` - что в консоли браузера?

Comment: @Igor, config.json:3 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
pult.htm:29 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at pult.htm:29
banner.png:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND, данные ошибки в консоли браузера